# Filtering unique data with Column combinations in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list as following:

```
 public class MyClass
 {
    public int val1;
    public long val2;
    public string val3;
 }
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<MyClass> lstData=new List<MyClass>
        {
            new MyClass{val1=1,val2=2,val3="AA"},
            new MyClass{val1=1,val2=2,val3="BB"},
            new MyClass{val1=3,val2=4,val3="AA"},
            new MyClass{val1=3,val2=4,val3="BB"},
            new MyClass{val1=1,val2=2,val3="BB"},
            new MyClass{val1=3,val2=4,val3="AA"},

        };
    }
}
```

I want to get unique rows out of the list.In the above example following  lists are duplicate

```
{val1=1,val2=2,val3="BB"}
 {val1=3,val2=4,val3="AA"}
```

I want to eliminate the duplicate rows and get the distinct rows out of the list.
How I can do that?

Answer (score 3):

```
var result = lstData.GroupBy(x=>new {x.val1, x.val2, x.val3}, (x,y)=>y.First())
                    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your real class `MyClass` overrides `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, all you need is to add [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx):

```
lstData = lstData.Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to either implement `GetHashCode` and `Equals` methods on your `MyClass` class, or define custom class which implements `IEqualityComparer<MyClass>`.

```
public class MyClassEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<MyClass>
{
    private static Lazy<MyClassEqualityComparer> _instance = new Lazy<MyClassEqualityComparer>(() => new MyClassEqualityComparer());

    public static MyClassEqualityComparer Instance
    {
        get { return _instance.Value; }
    }

    private MyClassEqualityComparer() { }

    public bool Equals(MyClass x, MyClass y)
    {
        return x.val1 == y.val1 && x.val2 == y.val2 && x.val3 == y.val3;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(MyClass obj)
    {
        return obj.val1.GetHashCode() ^ obj.val2.GetHashCode() ^ obj.val3.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

With that you'll be able to use LINQ `Distinct()` method:

```
var distinct = lstData.Distinct(MyClassEqualityComparer.Instance).ToList();
```